# How to add fields dinamically (with a loop?) in ACF for Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've been looking for some help in other questions but none solved my doubts.
I have installed ACF in my Wordpress website that will allow editors to add events and related details. I created some fields inside a field group. 
Everything's fine apart from one field, *event_length* (indicates length in days of an event). 
This field accepts a number and **this number indicates the length of a particular event, in days**. 
When this field is populated with a value (let's call it n), a datetime picker field (so, another field), should be displayed below with label 'Day 1', so that editor can choose the date related to that day. **If value is 50, 50 datetime picker fields should be displayed below.** 
 I tried to use `add_row()` function but I have no idea how to use it according to *event_length* field value.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with ACF. However, if you figure out how repeater field works in acf you might be able to do this with a lot of coding...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `add_row` function and `load_field` filter combined

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/add_row/
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/

I know nothing about your code, but it could look something like this:

```
function pre_populate_date_rows($date_repeater) {
  if (!have_rows($date_repeater) {
    $event_length = get_field('event_length', $post_id);
    
    for($i = 0; i < $event_length; i++) {
      add_row($field->key, array('time' => get_date(), $post_id);
    }
  }
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=date_repeater', 'pre_populate_date_rows');
```

Note that I do not know if `$field->key` is an actual property but you should be able to debug how to get the key from the $field object. Also note that you need to populate your row with default data so I just used the current datetime via `get_date`